Azure Data Factory trigger Databricks cluster termination
I have a scenario when I have to trigger the termination of the Databricks all purpose cluster from ADF pipeline.
What would be the best approach to achieve that? I tried using the linked service but the only options I see is to run code in the specified cluster using notebooks etc.
To clarify: I know that using job cluster or setting auto-termination will be a better solution, but this is for experimental purposes and I have to do it for some reason.

I ended up with calling the Databricks API with proper cluster ID through Web Activity as described in
https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/clusters/delete
